# как узнать значение определенной ячейки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой dataframe у столбца Unnamed И первой строки тип данных: object.
Есть год и число (например 2022 и 3) и задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести значение ячейки на пересечении строки 2022 года и столбца 3, учитывая, что год и число могут меняться каждый раз, а вывод должен быть корректным.(те нельзя просто вывеси значение строки 111 и столбца 3).
По сути мне нужно найти ячейку с нужным годом и тогда смогу вывести в строке
[индекс ячейки с годом] + 5 + число.
Пробовала найти строку с годом с помощью contains или с помощью обрезания , не вышло.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: Ну по идее как-то так: `df.loc[df['Unnamed'] == '2022', '3']`, но тут надо ещё выяснить год у вас строка или число и тоже самое касается и названия столбца. Строки нужно писать в кавычках, а числа не нужно. Покажите `print(df.columns)` и `print(df['Unnamed'].unique()` для начала, где `df` - ваш датафрейм.

Comment: вот что выводит при использовании того, что вы написали: Series([], Name: 3, dtype: object)

Comment: Странно. Но вообще это базовые понятия при работе с датафреймами, разбирайтесь, направление я вам дал.

Comment: df.colums показал что тип object ( я писала выше).

Comment: Да не нужен тип, нужно посмотреть, как названия колонок печатаются - с кавычками или без.

Comment: print(df['Unnamed'].unique() на это выдает следующее:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: Такое впечатление, что `df` - это не датафрейм, а что-то другое у вас )

Comment: с кавычками пишутся

Comment: Так, а попробуйте `print(df.loc[df['Unnamed'] == '2022'])` без указания столбца, строки то выдаст?

Comment: А попробуйте `2022` без кавычек: `print(df.loc[df['Unnamed'] == 2022])`, ну и странно, что у вас `print(df['Unnamed'].unique())` не работает, ерунда какая-то.

Comment: данные в вопросе должны быть в воспроизводимом виде. вы уже целую дискуссию устроили в комментариях, и даже не выяснили, датафрейм это у вас или что. голосую за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: и кстати, у вас уже есть один вопрос с непринятым до сих пор ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранила как новую таблицу и прочитала ее,

```
(df_5 = df5.to_csv('df_5.csv')
df_6 = pd.read_csv('df_5.csv'))
```

год (y) нашла с помощью contains

```
(ar1 = df_6[df_6['Unnamed: 0'].str.contains(y, na = False)]),
```

потом нашла индекс столбца с нужным месяцем (m)

```
(num_col = ar1.columns.get_loc(m))
```

и вывела его значение

```
(res = ar1.iat[0,num_col])
```